# What is the second 'invalidate' argument to Readable.subscribe?

Tags: svelte

The docs only say: `invalidate cleanup callback`. Not very informative.
https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-store#types-readable

Anyone got a little bit more info on this? Maybe a tiny example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open [issue about this](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/8298).

I dug through the commit history and found that the function was added in [this commit](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/commit/a2ff93cb721b786f34e467b9bddfbf6eebcfde43).

> glitch-free reactive stores

The invalidate callback is used internally by `derived` to update a local `pending` state, which, from the looks of it, is used to prevent subscribers from being called until all dependencies have "settled".

The change was added between versions `3.0.0-alpha6` and `3.0.0-alpha7`.

The test case added with the commit looks like this:

```js
it('prevents glitches', () => {
    const lastname = writable('Jekyll');
    const firstname = derive(lastname, n => n === 'Jekyll' ? 'Henry' : 'Edward');

    const fullname = derive([firstname, lastname], names => names.join(' '));

    const values = [];

    const unsubscribe = fullname.subscribe(value => {
        values.push(value);
    });

    lastname.set('Hyde');

    assert.deepEqual(values, [
        'Henry Jekyll',
        'Edward Hyde'
    ]);

    unsubscribe();
});
```

Before the fix, the `values` array ends up as:

```js
[
  'Henry Jekyll',
  'Edward Jekyll', // <- Should not be here
  'Edward Hyde',
]
```

Since the function is not documented, it probably is intended only for internal use.

Comment: That's some high quality sleuthing you did just there.

I found the place invalidate gets called because of it: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/master/packages/svelte/src/runtime/store/index.js#L51

It's in the `writable.set` implementation. It calls a subscribers invalidate fn just before calling the subscriber with the new value.

Comment: First thing I looked at, unfortunately did not explain anything 

Comment: And this is the invalidate fn in the derived implementation: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/master/packages/svelte/src/runtime/store/index.js#L168

I understand the test case, but the code implementation is impenetrable to me.

But yeah I concur that invalidate seems like an internal implementation detail. I would love it if the documentation would tell me that. Or just not tell me about the existence of invalidate at all.